# Qt's random generator and threads (qsrand and qrand)

Tags: multithreading, qt, random

I have an application that uses a thread pool (`QThreadPool`, own instance, i.e. not the global instance) and runs some tasks (`QRunnable`) by submitting the tasks to the queue of the pool.
In my main function, I do:

```
qsrand(QTime(0,0,0).secsTo(QTime::currentTime()));
```

My tasks make use of random numbers. The problem, however, is that the numbers are not random between different executions of the application. For instance, if I run the application twice, I will see the same random numbers as output and not different numbers as I would expect. 
(of course, I wait longer than a second between running the application).

If I put the statement above at the beginning of each runnable in the `run()` method, the behavior changes and I get different numbers between executions.
Do I need to execute the statement above in each thread (respectively runnable, in the run() function)? That seems to be nasty and not a nice solution.

Is there a way to set a global seed that holds for any threads such that the aforementioned problem can be avoided?

What am I doing wrong - I appreciate any inputs.

Comment: Have you tried to print the time with QDebug to see if they differ? Would it be possible to paste a bit more code, including the actual random number call rather than just qsrand?